# Autocomplete in IOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am making IOS app in Xamarin IOS in MAC. In toolbar there is textbox but there is not autocomplete field like in Android toolbar. So is there a way i can make textbox into autocomplete field in IOS Xamarin and connect it with JSON or array. Because in Xamarin Guide there is no example or guide for autocomplete in ios.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iOS texfeild with tableview to provide the autocomplete option. You can check this my blog entry http://appliedcodelog.com/2015/09/xamarinios-location-autocomplete-by.html implemented autocomplete option by binding the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is really for answering technical questions about things you tried. Asking if something exists is better task for google in which on the first results page I found a [monotouch autocomplete demo on github](https://github.com/LucasMoffitt/Monotouch-AutoCompleteDemo) and this example for [autocomplete in xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/AutoComplete).

Comment: Mono is now Xamarin and the link you included in your answer is old. I tried that link already, this api don't work because its old.

Answer (score 0):

New updated api for autocomplete in Xamarin IOS
https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField