# AutoComplete Field and multiple selection

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, telerik

I am developping in Xamarin IOS, I need a control that can support autocomplete as I type in and which can receive more than one data. I used to work with Telerik for Web Dev, and I want the control I am looking for to do the same thing as a **RadAutoCompleteBox** in Telerik would Do. Is there any control that can do that? Or Do I have to implement this myself in Xamarin IOS. if so, can I have a link or a tutorial that could help me with  that?

Answer (score 1):

You could search the google first and you will find there are several duplicate questions already there.

Here are some links you can refer:

1. [syncfusion-autocomplete](https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios-ui-controls/autocomplete)

   The tutorial is here :[sfautocomplete/overview](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios/sfautocomplete/overview)
2. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622131/autocomplete-in-ios-xamarin), there are several suggestions.
3. Here is also a CustomControl of `AutoCompleteView` [Xamarin.CustomControls.AutoCompleteView](https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin-Custom-Controls/tree/master/src/Xamarin.CustomControls.AutoCompleteView)

If you want to implement this yourself in `Xamarin IOS`. You can use [Searchbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/searchbar) and get something like `AutoCompleteView`. Enter the text in the `searchBar` and put the search results in a `tableview` under the `searchBar`.