# How to Use AutoCompleteTextView With Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Implement AutocompleteTextview in xamarin forms,
till now i have achieved the customisation and look which i need to for my Auto Complete Bar, 
but the thing where i am stuck is filling of data to Dataadapter from Shared Library also i am not getting what text is selected inside the Entry bar, so could anyone help me how can i bind my list from pcl to native and also i need two way data to Text Property

here is the code which i had implemented till now

my common class

```
public class AutoCompleteViewv3 : View
{
    public AutoCompleteViewv3()
    {

    }  

}
```

My Android Implementation

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoSuggestBox), 
typeof(AutoCompleteViewRendererv3))]
  namespace PredictiveList.Droid
   {
   public class AutoCompleteViewRendererv3  : 
                      ViewRenderer<AutoCompleteViewv3, 
          AutoCompleteTextView>
{
    static string[] COUNTRIES = new string[] {
   "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", };

    public AutoCompleteViewRendererv3(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AutoCompleteViewv3> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;


        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TextEditorLayouts, null);

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, 
    Resource.Layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
        textView.Adapter = adapter;
        SetNativeControl(textView);
    }

    // Use the control here.
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
            return;

        // variable this.Control is the AutoCompleteTextView, so you an manipulate it.
    }
}
```

}

For Ios i am still trying to implemented

Comment: You can use some third-part controls to achieve the AutoCompleteTextView, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296637/autocomplete-field-and-multiple-selection/54302293#54302293).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT we are not allowed to use 3rd party Controls

Comment: Ok, I will try you code.

Answer (score 0):

please check [Code here for Auto complete](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/autocomplete-textfield-with-suggestion-dropdown-in-xamairn-forms)